# Shell script to delete logs when the disk space reaches 90%

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting, cron

I  to develop a shell script to delete the logs automatically once the disk space reaches 90%.

I can add this shell script to crontab jobs.

Comment: What have you got so far in your script?  Is there a reason why you're not using `logrotate` to manage the log files?

Comment: @EightBitTony not every OS has `logrotate` as part of the initial installation (e.g. Solaris and FreeBSD).

@chandra what OS are you using?

Comment: @forquare. Cmon, is not THAT hard to install logrotate after installing the base system...

Comment: @nwildner we don't know what logs the OP wants to delete, and may not have privileges to install `logrotate`.  More information would be good.

Comment: If he has privilege to edit crontab, he likely have privileges to configure logrotate. He didn't said that he was using "unprivileged user crontab wit `crontab -e`". That is why I am assuming the supercow access :) . And if his system administrators do not use `logrotate` they are probably neglecting the BASICS of server maintenance.

Comment: @forquare I asked if there was a reason why they weren't using logrotate, it's not installed, or I can't install it, or it doesn't exist for my distribution are valid answers.  I didn't say 'use logrotate'.

Comment: @nwildner unless `logadm` or `newsyslog` are more appropriate for the platform, perhaps?  My point being, specifics are assumptions without more information.

Comment: @EightBitTony - Linux OS

Comment: Let's wait for more information. However, this user does not seems to accept answers neither comment to much on his questions. @chandraprakash. And what about the other things people asked you? Are you `root` of this server? Is `logrotate` or any other logging solution installed? What DISTRIBUTION of "Linux OS" are you using?

Comment: @nwildner - i am not the root of this server. logrotate is not installed and OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)..

Comment: @chandraprakash as a side point, you may find people more willing to put in effort if you accepted suitable answers on your previous questions.  People like answering questions, but they're even more likely to do so when you use the system and accept previous answers.

Comment: @chandraprakash ARE you SURE? Not even MINIMAL CDs of CentOS comes without logrotate - https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOSMinimalCD6.0 - Not saying you are a liar, but this situation is very unlikely...

Answer (score 4):

Would not be better if you compress your files and keep less of older logs instead of spending time creating a script? ***THIS is why logrotate exists.***

Take a look at your `logrotate.conf`. It should start with something like this:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

Uncomment the `compress` option, and change the `rotate` to 3 for example and see if it fits on your disk space. It needs to fit your company needs too. We have one server where login information needs to be kept during eighteen months for legal reasons, so we changed the login files to rotate monthly:

```
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    minsize 1M
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 18
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    minsize 1M
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 18
}
```

You can create specific rotate rules if you point to the file or directory, and put parameters between curly brackets.

**Not a privileged user?**. It's not a problem at all, since `cron` and `logrotate` can be configured to run without the need to be root:

- [Configuring logrotate without root access (per user log rotation)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405663/configuring-logrotate-without-root-access-per-user-log-rotation)